# Python: how to get random contiguous sets?

Tags: python, scikit-learn

This is what I get by running `train_test_split`

```
In [1]:train_test_split([1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10],test_size = 0.2)
Out[1]: [[10, 3, 6, 5, 4, 2, 7, 9], [8, 1]]
```

However, what I want is a contiguous set, i.e.

```
[[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 10], [8, 9]]

or 

[[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 8, 9, 10], [6, 7]]

or 

[[1, 2, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10], [3, 4]]
```

****** Please note that the following is also considered contiguous**

```
[[2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9], [10, 1]]
```

How can I do this ?

Answer (score 0):

Can you try the following:

```
import random

def custom_train_test_split(X, test_size=0.2):
  temp = X.copy()
  split_size = int(len(temp) * test_size)
  start = random.randint(0, len(X) - split_size)
  end = start + split_size
  test = temp[start:end]
  del temp[start:end]
  return [temp, test]

X = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]

print(custom_train_test_split(X, test_size=0.2))
print(custom_train_test_split(X, test_size=0.2))
print(custom_train_test_split(X, test_size=0.2))
```

Output:

```
[[1, 2, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10], [3, 4]]
[[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 8, 9, 10], [6, 7]]
[[3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10], [1, 2]]
```

Comment: Why `start = random.randint(0, 8)`? Should it be `start = random.randint(0, len(X) - split_size)`?